# How can i wait for animation to end in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, animation

I'm using animate.css to do some animations on my site, but i want a certain animation to occur right after the other one ended, for example i have this css:

```
.pageRenderer.ng-enter{
    animation:  fadeIn 1s;
}

.pageRenderer.ng-leave{
    animation: bounceOutLeft 1s;
}
```

And this simple html:

```
 <div ng-repeat='page in pages' style='position:relative'>
                <div ng-if="$index == pageToShow" class='pageRenderer'>
                    <h2>{{page.title}}</h2>
                    <div ng-repeat='quest in page.quests'>
                        <div ng-switch on="quest.ui.type">
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-select-single" >
                                <div ms-select-single quest='quest'></div>
                            </div>
                           ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When i turn to next page (I have a button that does it), i want first to my ng-leave to do it's job and leave, and only than do the enter, not simultaneously...

Is it possible without any use of angular at all? if not, What are to be my options?

Comment: You can use $timeout, set the timeout to 1000ms.

Answer (score 2):

You can try different solutions:

add a delay to the ng-leave class

```
animation-delay: 1s;
```

put your animations when ng-enter is active and ng-leave is active (not sure about this solution, I usually use transitions and not animations, but give it a try)

```
.pageRenderer.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    animation:  fadeIn 1s;
}

.pageRenderer.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    animation: bounceOutLeft 1s;
}
```

Comment: Usually using `ng-animate` works, but sometimes I find I have elements that are not present in time as result of the animations having finished; in that case I used this:

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    // Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be present on the dom.
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('#abc')), 5000);

From the Protractor API documentation: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf